# Treeview NavigateUrl absolut path sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, navigation, treeview, treenode

I have a treeview of files and i need to download those files from another page.
So Im setting the NavigateUrl to the downloadpage but im getting the currentpage path and downloadpages path.

```
foreach (FileInfo file in currentDir.GetFiles())
            {
                TreeNode nodeFile = new TreeNode(file.Name, file.FullName);
                nodeFile.NavigateUrl = "_layouts/Download.aspx?file="+file.FullName;
                nodeFile.Target = "_blank";
                nodeFile.ImageUrl = "_layouts/images/DOC_SP16.gif";
                currentNode.ChildNodes.Add(nodeFile);
            }
```

When i click the node it's navigating to

```
http://localhost/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/MyLib/_layouts/Download.aspx?file=c:Somefile.txt
```

but what i want is the path to the root URL like this.

```
http://localhost/_layouts/Download.aspx?file=ownload.aspx?file=c:Somefile.txt
```

I don't want to move my download.aspx to that location.
Anybody got a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simple soulution i was looking for insted of

```
nodeFile.NavigateUrl = "_layouts/Download.aspx?file="+file.FullName;
```

I put an "/" in the beginning of the path

```
nodeFile.NavigateUrl = "/_layouts/Download.aspx?file="+file.FullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will only work on site collection that are on the root of a WebAppliction.

I suggest to use the [`SPUtility.GetServerRelativeUrlFromPrefixedUrl method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getserverrelativeurlfromprefixedurl.aspx) to calculate the actual correct url.

If you want to target an application page at SPWeb level, use:

```
var theUrl =  SPUtility.GetServerRelativeUrlFromPrefixedUrl(   
    "~site/_layouts/Download.aspx?file="+file.FullName
    );
```

If you want to target an application page at SPSite level, use:

```
var theUrl =  SPUtility.GetServerRelativeUrlFromPrefixedUrl(   
    "~sitecollection/_layouts/Download.aspx?file="+file.FullName
    );
```

This will ensure the correctness of the url, wherever your code runs.

As a side note, you may visit the [SharePoint dedicated StackExchange site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)